# Dynamic SQL - long execution time - first time only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have stored procedure which is building dynamic SQL statement depending on its input parameters and then executed it.

One of the queries is causing time outs, so I have decided to check it. The first time (and only the first time) the issue statement is executed it is slow (30 secs - 45 secs) and every next execute takes 1-2 seconds.

In order to reproduce the issue, I am using

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

I am really confused where the problem is, because ordinary if SQL statement is slow, it is always slow. Now, it has long execution time only the first time.

Is is possible, the itself to be slow and needs optimization or the problem can be caused by something else?

The execution plan is below, but for me there is nothing strange with it:

[image]

Comment: Clear the caches and then run the queries with SET STATISTICS IO ON; Look at the number of reads (especially physical reads or read-ahead), then without clearing the cache run it again and look at the number of reads, if there were a lot of physical/read-ahead reads that are now logical reads, it is likely that SQL server just needs to do a lot of IO to satisfy the query, once this data is cached in memory it is a lot faster.

Comment: @steoleary You are right. All physical reads become logical reads. So, this explains why the situation appears. I guess, the only thing to fix that is to try to optimize the query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your reply to my comment, it would appear that the first time this query runs it is performing a lot of physical reads or read-ahead reads, meaning that a lot of IO is required to get the right pages into the buffer pool to satisfy this query.

Once pages are read into the buffer pool (memory) they generally stay there so that physical IO is not required to read them again (you can see this is happening as you indicated that the physical reads are converted to logical reads the second time the query is run).  Memory is orders of magnitude faster than disk IO, hence the difference in speed for this query.

Looking at the plan, I can just about see that every read operation is being done against the clustered index of the table.  As the clustered index contains every column for the row it is potentially fetching more data per row than is actually required for the query.

Unless you are selecting every column from every table, I would suggest that creating non-clustered covering indexes that satisfy this query (that are as narrow as possible), this will reduce the IO requirement for the query and make it less expensive the first time round.

Of course this may not be possible/viable for you to do, in which case you should either just take the hit on the first run and not empty the caches, or rewrite the query itself to be more efficient and perform less reads.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple the reason 1st and very 1st time it takes longer and then all later executions are done fairly quickly. the reason behind this mystery is "CACHED EXECUTION PLANS".

> While working with Stored Procedures, Sql server takes the following
>   steps.
>
> 1) Parse Syntax of command. 
>  2) Translate to Query Tree.
>  3) Develop
>   Execution Plan. 
>  4) Execute.

The 1st two steps only take place when you create a Stored Procedure.

3rd step only takes place on very 1st Execution or if the CACHED PLAN has been flushed from the CACHE MEMORY.

Fourth Step takes place on every execution, and this is the only step that takes place after the very 1st execution if the Plan is still in cache memory.

In your case its quite understandable that very 1st execution took long and then later it gets executed fairly quickly.

To  reproduce the "issue" you executed `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` AND `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` commanda which basically Flushes the `BUFFER CACHE MEMORY` and causes your stored procedure to create a new Execution plan on it next execution. Hope this will clear the fog a little bit :)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, but on the production site, the procedure is executed a lot of times and everything is OK. Only with one specific input the delay appears. I am using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` in order to reproduce the issue only.

Comment: `DO NOT EVER` execute these two DBCC commands on your Production server , unless you have a very very good reason to do so.

Comment: Well in that case you need to look at the Execution plan with that particular input that slow downs the procedure and an ordinarary input and see how the plan is different and what changes you can makes to get a consistant and efficient execution plan for it.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I am executing them on my local back up :-) The advice that gives me @steoleary explain it all - the first time I have a lot of physical reads that are after that turn into logical, so the issue is query itself.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when a Stored procedure is first created, or its statistics etc reset, it will take the first value passed into the Stored Procedure as the 'default' value for the stored procedure.  It will then try to optimize itself based off of that.

To stop that from happening, there are a couple of things you can do.

You could potentially use the Query hints feature to mark certain variables as Unknown.  So, as an example, at the end of the stored procedure you could put something along the lines of:

```
select * from foo where foo.bar = @myParam option (optimize for @myParam unknown)
```

As another approach, you could force the SQL plan to be re-compiled each time - which might be a good idea if your stored procedure is highly variable in the type of SQL it generates.  The way you'd do that is:

```
select * from foo where foo.bar = @myParam option (optimize recompile)
```

Hope this helps.